# how to receive the message form remote use boost::asio?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I want to write a web server use boost::asio,I can send the message to remote client but can't receive the message from client.I have installed the boost library on my operating system.My code:
AsyncServer.h:

```
#ifndef HTTPSERVER_ASYNCSERVER_H
#define HTTPSERVER_ASYNCSERVER_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _WIN32_WINNT    0X0501  //fix the warning in VC compile
#endif

class AsyncServer {
private:
    io_service &ios;
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
public:
    //init method
    AsyncServer(io_service &io,ip::tcp::endpoint &ep):ios(io),acceptor(io,ep){
        start();
    };
    void start();
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::socket> sock_ptr;
    void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, sock_ptr sock);
    void write_handler(const boost::system::error_code&);
    void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
};
#endif //HTTPSERVER_ASYNCSERVER_H
```

My code AsyncServer.cpp:

```
#include "AsyncServer.h"

void AsyncServer::start() {
    sock_ptr sock(new ip::tcp::socket(ios));
    //call back accept_handler method when get url request
    acceptor.async_accept(*sock, boost::bind(&AsyncServer::accept_handler,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error,sock));
}

void AsyncServer::accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, sock_ptr sock) {
    if(ec)
        return;
    //print the info from client
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf1;
    sock->async_receive(streambuf1, handler);
    cout << "remote ip:" << sock->remote_endpoint().address() << endl;
    cout << "remote port:" << sock->remote_endpoint().port() << endl;
    //send message to client by async method, call back write method
    sock->async_write_some(
            buffer("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nhello world"),
            bind(&AsyncServer::write_handler,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error)
    );
    //start the start method by async
    start();
}

void AsyncServer::write_handler(const boost::system::error_code &) {
    printf("send msg complete!\n");
}

void AsyncServer::handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    printf("read OK!\n");
}
```

my code main.cpp:

```
#include "AsyncServer.h"

int main(){
    try
    {
        io_service ios;
        ip::tcp::endpoint serverep(ip::tcp::v4(),9876);
        AsyncServer server(ios, serverep);
        ios.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04LTS,the gcc's version is 4.8.2,I use this command to compile the code:g++ -o main.cpp AsyncServer.h AsyncServer.cpp -lboost -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem,then there are some error show in terminal `/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:614:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
AsyncServer.cpp:18:44: note:   cannot convert ‘((AsyncServer*)this)->AsyncServer::handler’ (type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’) to type ‘boost::asio::socket_base::message_flags {aka int}’
     sock->async_receive(streambuf1, handler);`;I knew that the error code is `sock->async_receive(streambuf1, handler);` in AsyncServer.cpp.How to fix the bug and receive the message from remote client.